# Why does my navigation menu disappear when the browser window get resized?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, toggle, navbar

HTML

```css
  html {
     height: 100%;
    }
    body {
         background-image: url("https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2000/1*M6iNwOtplNTw1EOTcUklkQ.png");
         background-size: cover; 
         background-position: center;
    
          color: white !important;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    
    nav .navbar-nav li a {
      color: white !important;
      font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 700;
      }
    
     .navbar-brand {
      color: white !important;
      }
    
      #content {
     text-align: center;
     padding-top: 27%; 
     text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>James McGill</title>
     <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">J.M</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About me</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact me</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

I just can't seem to figure out why this is happening guys.
Please have a look at my code and give me some suggestions on how I can make it work.

I have added the button and icon for the toggle as you can see on the HTML code but it is not showing up on the browser.

What did I do wrong here? Let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: It's Bootstrap 4 Jake.

Comment: Seems like a background image is expected in the <span> that's a child of the button, but isn't there. There is simply nothing to show.

Comment: Your navbar isn't gone altogether, it's just invisible for some reason (click the top right and it will drop down the nav).

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the bootstrap class `navbar` and `navbar-collapse` used in your div: here:
`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">`

These are bootstrap classes and hence when you use them as is: they collapse when the screen is below 768px:

`@media (min-width: 768px)`

The explanations to the navbar css is on the [Bootstrap site](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#supported-content)

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix would be to add the *navbar-light bg-light* or *navbar-dark bg-dark* and  class to the *nav* tag.
**Why?**
When you take a look at the navbar.scss file and scroll down to *.navbar-light* you will see that nested inside there is a *.navbar-toggler-icon* which sets the burger-ish image when the navbar is collapsed.
Of course you can customize this by using own css. I would refer you to the bootstrap docs to get this done.
[navbar color-schemes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#color-schemes)
[theming](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/)

```css
  html {
     height: 100%;
    }
    body {
         background-image: url("https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2000/1*M6iNwOtplNTw1EOTcUklkQ.png");
         background-size: cover; 
         background-position: center;
    
          color: white !important;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    
    nav .navbar-nav li a {
      color: white !important;
      font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 700;
      }
    
     .navbar-brand {
      color: white !important;
      }
    
      #content {
     text-align: center;
     padding-top: 27%; 
     text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>James McGill</title>
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-md sticky-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">J.M</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About me</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact me</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tim. Is there a default class to make the toggle button all default white. As you can see its not very visible at the moment.

Comment: Sorry I forgot something. You should also add a background. You can do this by adding bg-light or bg-dark to the nav tag. I updated my answer. 
If my answer is helpful you could honor it by pressing the up arrow and the green check mark.

Comment: Sorry Tim, I'd love to but I don't have enough reputations.